# Get outer id of a html tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one scenario such that using while clicking a div I have to get the `id` of its outer div.

For example :

```
<div class = "top-class" id="top1">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="1" class="xx"></div>
    <td><div id="2" class="xx"></div>
    <td><div id="3" class="xx"></div>
  </tr>
</div>


<div class = "top-class" id="top2">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="5" class="xx"></div>
    <td><div id="6" class="xx"></div>
    <td><div id="7" class="xx"></div>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Now on clickig `xx` I must get the `id` of div with class name "top-class" it belongs to. I have coded like this but didnt know how to get the id. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
$('.xx').click(function(){
     alert($(this).prevAll('.top-class').attr('id')); //code fails though
});
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `div` cannot be the direct child of a `tbody`  element to wrap `tr` as you are.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid because we could not find `<table></table>` tag there. Also you cannot use DIV as parent of `<tr>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend on the examples provided. jQuery uses the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), rather than `click` these days. So what you should be doing is something like the following:

```
$('.xx').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var top_id = $this.closest('.top-class').attr('id');

    alert(top_id);
});
```